# Finding out who broke the most builds in Teamcity

Tags: build-automation, teamcity

Is there a simple way of finding out how many successful/broken builds a user has generated in Teamcity? We need this to find out who buys beers on friday :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer seems to be no. There is no simple way to do this but it isn't impossible. Check out this post on the JetBrains forum. Is that Matrix reference a joke?

http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5239286#5239286

There is a build history tab on the agent details page. But you cannot do much with it (not in version 5.01 of Teamcity anyway). It does not even allow sorting on the results column. Depending on how many builds you have per week, it could be possible to do a quick manual scan of all the failed builds per agent pretty quickly.

EDIT: This is definitely possible in Teamcity 7.0 via the new [REST API](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin).

It would look something like this:

http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:bt284/builds?status=FAILURE&user=id:1

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible now in TeamCity 6 using it's support for custom charting:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Custom+Chart